# Discrete Event simulation using Queue structure c++

Tags: c++, queue

I need to read from a text file name called data.txt. I have stuck in the file reading. Therefore I cannot continue in the main program.  
 In the text file format is 
arrival time      servce time 
**________**      **__________** 
0.2                     2.4 
1.5                     3.3 
3.5                     1.3 

There are 100 records in the text file. How can I read those 100 records in to a queue data. I have used struct named "cust" for this. 
In this program I need to find the average waiting time of the customer, maximum waiting time of a customer and also the The probability that a customer has to wait in a queue for 10 minutes or more. 
And also assume that there is only one cash counter in the setup. 
Here is the code I have done so far.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



struct cust {
    unsigned int ID;
    float arrivalTime;
    float serviceTime;
};

struct  QueueNode       
{                       // declaration of QueueNode to
    cust item;          // store items in queue 
    QueueNode *next;    // as linked list
};

class Queue
{
    public:
        Queue ();
        bool isEmpty();
        bool enqueue(cust newItem);
        bool dequeue(cust &data);
        bool getFront(cust &data);
        bool getBack(cust &data);
        int size();
        void showQueue();

    private:
        QueueNode *frontPointer;
        QueueNode *backPointer;
        int length;
};

Queue :: Queue()
{
    frontPointer=NULL;
    backPointer=NULL;
    length=0;
}

bool Queue :: isEmpty()
{
    if (length==0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool Queue :: enqueue(cust newItem)
{
    QueueNode *pnew = new QueueNode;
    if(pnew == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    pnew->item = newItem;
    pnew->next = NULL;

    if (isEmpty())
    {
        frontPointer=pnew;
        backPointer=pnew;
    }
    else
    {
        backPointer->next=pnew;
        backPointer=pnew;
    }
    length++;

    return true;
}

bool Queue :: dequeue(cust &data)
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        return false;
    }
    QueueNode *pnew = frontPointer;
    data = frontPointer->item;

    if(frontPointer==backPointer)
    {
        frontPointer=NULL;
        backPointer=NULL;
    }
    else 
    frontPointer = frontPointer->next;
    length--;
    delete pnew;
    return true;
}

bool Queue :: getFront(cust &data)
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        return false;
    }
    data = frontPointer->item;
    return true;
}

bool Queue :: getBack(cust &data)
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        return false;
    }

    data = backPointer->item;
    return true;
}

int Queue :: size ()
{
    return length;
}

void Queue :: showQueue()
{
    if (!isEmpty())
    {
        QueueNode *pnew = frontPointer;
        while (pnew !=NULL)
        {
            cout << pnew->item.ID << " ";
            pnew = pnew->next;
        }
    }

    else 
    {
        cout << "......" << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{

    //I need file input and other calculations performing at here
    Queue cQueue;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To read files you need to use `fstream` and store them in `cust` as an array.

```
fstream f;
f.open("data.txt", ios::in);

cust arr[100];

for(int  i = 0; i < 100; 1++)
{
     f >> arr[i].arrivalTime >> arr[i].serviceTime;
     QueueObj.enqueue(arr[i]);
}
f.close();
```

Looking at your Queue class, I see that the item `ID` is never used; only `arrivalTime` and `serviceTime`. Make sure you find a use for that or your `showQueue()` method is useless.

Comment: Actually I have used id as first line of the record as one and second line of the text file as 2. So later I can use that. So what should I do then ? And one more thing , that is arrival time and service time space is a tab.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Your original post is somewhat difficult to understand as well.